# Grails : Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 10 sec

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, grails

> Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:10000]

Whenever we are connecting to web app with Socket, it throws this error and socket gets disconnected.

Even after doing following things, problem still persists -

1. Scaled up AWS EC2 from micro to large
2. In `/etc/my.cnf`

   ```
   wait_timeout = 28800
   interactive_timeout = 28800
   ```
3. Added following configurations under both Development as well as production environment.

   ```
          maxActive = 50
          minIdle = 5
          maxIdle = 25
          maxWait = 10000
          maxAge = 10 * 60000
   ```

has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Ultimately you connection pool has been exhausted.  Have you verified where you are obtaining and releasing connections?

Comment: Which connection you are talking about? Socket connection or DB Connection?